# Given a stream of integers find the average

Tags: average

There is a continuous stream of integers and the average must be calculated at any given instance using only memory.

Comment: Please add some code examples. What does the stream look like? Is it evergrowing?

Comment: An example would be good to illustrate the requirement. Not really clear still imho.

Comment: Also, show what you've tried.

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment.  Why not post the assignment, verbatim, as it was provided so we can offer suggestions?  And overflowing `c` and `s` has nothing to do with efficiency.  But if you're worried about overflow, use a long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a nanosecond resolution, your item count will overflow within a few days as well.

However, you can - instead of keeping the sum - retain the old average value and reweigh it when a new item arrives.

```
private static void average(int... amount) {
    double average = (double) amount[0];
    for (double i = 1; i < amount.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("average: %d%n", (int) average);
        double newWeight = (i + 1d) / i;
        double newAverage = average / newWeight;
        double thisAverage = (amount[(int)i]) / (i+1d);
        average = newAverage + thisAverage;
    }
    System.out.printf("average: %d%n", (int) average);
}
```

As for why this works, let's say you're going through the values

> 3, 2, 5

The first value will result in an average of

> 3 / 1 = 3

(with the "1" being the amount of values).

Now, the 2 arrives. This means we want (3+2)/2, or (3/1)/2 + (2/2), so we divide the previous average "3" by (1+2)/2. New average is now

> 3/2 + 2/2 = 2.5

Now the 5 arrives. Now we want

> (3+2+5)/3 = (3+2)/3 + 5/3

or - because we don't have the 3 and 2 in (3+2) anymore -

> = (3+2)/2 * 2/3

(3+2)/2 is the old average, 2 is the old count, and 3 is the new count.

Comment: Perfect, this was the one I was looking for. Thank you. Can you kindly explain it with an example of how this works ? Thank you again.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The Java 8 platform provides an [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) that allows you to simply call [average()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--).

```java
int[] allInts = { 1, 2, 3, ..., n };
OptionalDouble average = IntStream.of(allInts).average();
```

I don't know what you 'stream' of integers looks like, so if you update your question, I can update my answer.

Comment: By a stream of integers I mean there's an input request at a rate of 1 request per second. And I can't use any internal libraries for computing the average. Is there any efficient algorithm to calculate the average at any given time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigDecimal` to retain the sum and average; that doesn't overflow.

```
public void test(int[] values) {
    BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (int count = 0; count < values.length; count++) {
        sum = sum.add(new BigDecimal(values[count]));
        System.out.printf("%s/%d = %s%n", sum, (count+1), sum.divide(new BigDecimal(count+1)));
    }
}
```

But I don't think it's worth the hassle. In most cases it should be sufficient to just use `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: If the input request rate is increased from 1 request per second to 1 request per nano second will it still work ? And can I take advantage over the fact that request value is gonna range from 0 to 100 and reset the values to avoid overflow because the interviewer asked me not to use BigInteger or BigDecimal class.

Comment: Going from 1 second to 1 nano-second?  Can't use BigDecimal? Now you're moving the goal posts.  And as an aside, It's beyond belief that companies actually ask these types of questions.

Comment: Ya I had the same feeling when the interviewer changed it to 1 request per nano second.